# Changing selected value of dropdown from angularjs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularjs to dynamically add options to a select list using services.

```
app.service('myService',function() {
var dropdown = [{id:1,name:'one'},{id:2,name:'two'}];
this.getDropdown = function(){
  return dropdown;
};
this.add = function(id,name) {      
      dropdown.unshift({id:id,name:name});      
    };
});
```

In controller i'm binding dropdown model with service.

```
$scope.myDropdown = myService.getDropdown();
```

Now when i dynamically add a new item in dropdown through myService.add(id,name) function, it is added to the start of the list. I want newly added item to be selected as soon as its added.
Please guide me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending how your `ngModel` and `ngOptions` are setup - you have to set the `ngModel` after adding it to the select (short sample)

```
<select ng-model="mySelect" ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in myDropdown"></select>
```

And the controller:

```
$scope.myDropdown = myService.getDropdown();
dropdown.add(3, "Justin"); //Add to the select
$scope.myDropdown = myService.getDropdown(); //Rebind (not sure if this is needed or not)
$scope.mySelect = $scope.myDropdown[$scope.myDropdown.length - 1].id;
```

You can use `$watch` on a service and check the collection length:

```
$scope.$watch("myService.getDropdown()", function() {
    return value;
}, function(value) {
    if (value.length != $scope.myDropdown.length) {
        $scope.myDropdown = value;
        $scope.mySelect = $scope.myDropdown[$scope.myDropdown.length - 1].id;
    }
});
```

Comment: i was trying to achieve this through $watch